# Where does kafka store offsets of internal topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

__consumer_offsets store offsets of all kafka topics except internal topics such as *-changelog topics in case of streams. Where is this data stored?

Comment: I have read/consumed __consumer_offsets  already and found no info related to internal topics.

Comment: AFAIK, Changelog topics are always read from the beginning. There's no maintained consumer group information

Comment: @cricket_007 nope, Its not the case. We can read changelog topics from last read offset too.

Comment: Well, sure, if you don't care about previous state of the stream then you'd do that

Answer (score 2):

The term "internal topic" has two different meanings in Kafka:

1. Brokers: an internal topic is a topic that the cluster uses (like `__consumer_offsets`). A client cannot read/write from/to this topic.
2. Kafka Streams: topics that Kafka Streams creates automatically, are called internal topics, too.

However, those `-changelog` and `-repartition` topics that are "internal" topics from a Kafka Streams point of view, are regular topics from a broker point of view. Hence, offsets for both are stored in `__consumer_offsets` like for any other topic.

Note, that Kafka Streams will only commit offsets for `-repartition` topics, though. For `-changelog` topics no offsets are ever committed (Kafka Streams does some offset tracking on the client side though, and writes `-changelog` offsets into a local `.checkpoint` file).

Comment: Thanks. found the file. 1 more thing though, Is there any way we can control offsets for these internal -changelog topics? How do I make sure to read it from earliest offset?

Comment: You should not set those offsets manually. Kafka Streams takes care, that the content in the store matches the offsets in the checkpoint file (ie, all data with smaller offset is store in the store).

Comment: Thanks. When I manually deleted .checkpoint file, I found that streams re-created the file with latest offsets, How did stream gather the offset data? Is it stored somewhere in rocks-db data folder?

I am trying to solve a use case that I want to re-play changelog topic just in case my rocksdb data gets corrupted. So, I want to read change log topic from start without taking a restart.

Comment: If you delete the checkpoint file while Kafka Streams is running, if won't matter. Next time Kafka Streams commits, it will update the checkpoint file with the latest offsets from the topic (it tracks those internally).---`So, I want to read change log topic from start without taking a restart.` -> That is not possible.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and response. 1 more streams related doubt. 

In case of streams, lets suppose I have 10 instances of stream application and 100 partitions of some topic t1, Every instance will get 10 state stores / partitions of t1. But at the time of rebalancing, parition-instance mapping gets changed. Basically, partitions are not sticking to their instances even after sticky assignment policy is there. It might create a situation where all instances have data corresponding to all partitions. How do we take care of such scneraio so that data is mutual exclusively distributed?

Comment: `Basically, partitions are not sticking to their instances even after sticky assignment policy is there`. Why that? Kafka Streams tries to assigns tasks in a sticky manner since its first release. `It might create a situation where all instances have data corresponding to all partitions.` -> Each instance deletes old state after a configurable cleanup interval. Hence, this should not happen.